# YARA-L Rule - Chronicle

Tags: chronicle

I need to create a rule in this language that will trigger an alert every time a new user is created in GCP.

I need the rule to be suitable for the Chronicle environment.

I tried to do this -

```
rule new_user_creation{
    
    meta:
        author = "test"
        description = "Alert when a new user created"

    events:
        $create.target.user.userid = $user
        $create.metadata.event_type = "USER_CREATION"

    condition:
        $create

}
```

Thank you